# QApplication without display

Tags: c++, qt, qapplication

I using Qt3.3 and I'm trying to create an QApplication without display. 
I need to check signals from QSocket objects, and this is the reason that I need the QApplication.

I'm trying to do QApplication( 0, 0 ), but I'm getting "QApplication: invalid Display* argument.".

How is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the docs:

> QApplication::QApplication ( int &
>   argc, char ** argv, bool GUIenabled )
>
> Constructs an application object with
>   argc command line arguments in argv.
>   If GUIenabled is TRUE, a GUI
>   application is constructed, otherwise
>   a non-GUI (console) application is
>   created.
>
> Set GUIenabled to FALSE for programs
>   without a graphical user interface
>   that should be able to run without a
>   window system.

You get that message because the compiler probably binds against this constructor method

```
QApplication::QApplication(Display *dpy,HANDLE visual=0,HANDLE colormap=0)
```

treating your first zero as a NULL pointer to Display * (I guess this is a Display structure you can get from X11)